# how to encode Binary data to Text in c++/MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

Hi read the binary data from the zip file..I want to post the zip file through HTTP. and i want to encode and then want to send the zip file. so how  can i encode that one.

Comment: Not answerable. You need to think of what information is contained in those bits and bytes and then convert them to some other representation... nobody can help you with that if they don't know the binary format and what it represents.

Comment: You should really expand your question, explaining at least what kind of binary data is, if you know its format, what do you mean to "encode" it, what should be the output of this encoding, ... otherwise "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use a Base-64 encoding, that is also used, if I'm not wrong, to encode binary content into mails (that uses an old styled ASCII char format).
I'm sure you'll find many documents concerning Base-64 and meybe some simple code to use.
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different representations of data. Whilst some representations are in binary form there is no such thing as a standard binary format. Even for numbers, if you store them exactly as they appear in memory in their byte format, there are different representations due to endian-ness. On Intel the standard is little-endian.

What you need to do is first convert the "binary" which is a stream of bytes to data as in variables, classes, structs, etc.

Then you can use a text format to display them to the user in a readable format.

Comment: I need the post the binary data so need to encrypt it.

Comment: For others reading my answer he totally changed the question since I gave this answer.